# Kafka Connect MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka connect to upsert records into MySql. However, the default option is INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY REPLACE .. I am wondering if there is a way to change this - i.e: on duplicate keys, I would like to add the columns together.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the docs](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_config_options.html#writes) I would say the answer is no. `INSERT` or `UPSERT` is your choice.

You could address this in the database, or with a Kafka Streams app to perform the logical processing (adding fields together) as required.